# How does an air conditioning system with a water-soaked filter cools the hot air?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

> *In some household air conditioners used in dry climates, air is cooled by blowing it through a water-soaked filter, evaporating some of the water. How does this cool the air? Would such a system work well in a high-humidity climate? Why or why not?*

**Solution**:

First, I have made this graphical description of the air conditioning process:

[image]

My first thought was: The hot air which passes through the filter losses thermal energy when it contacts the water molecules; these ones gain energy from the the hot air molecules. In consequence, the water molecules which have reached the enough temperature -100ºC- get evaporated.

Finally, the air which have passed the filter is then cooled.

What do you think about this reasoning?

Answer (score 0):

Your reasoning and using energy transfer is a good start. Water does not have to all be 100deg C to evaporate. Some of the molecules have more energy than others and some can break free and escape as a gas.

But the real key is int he nature of water. The energy to evaporate water is very high compared to just getting hotter. In fact, it takes a lot of energy to just go from liquid to vapor were the vapor is no hotter than the liquid.

I think of it as the conversion to vapor takes energy from the water and the water is cooled (has less heat). Check Heat of Vaporization for water and compare it to the energy to increase temperature by 1 deg.

Now, how will humidity affect this?